# Idiom for the situation 'when people call it a big mistake but it actually is a small one"

Tags: idiom-request

I want an idiom for a situation like this:

> when I do a small mistake and people start telling other people that I have done a big mistake when the mistake is really small.

Comment: Are you only asking about a "mistake" or any issue/problem?

Comment: @AIQ it can be both issue/problem and mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remember, we **make mistakes**, not **do mistakes**.

This idiom describes your situation the best:

**[Make a mountain out of a molehill](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Make_a_mountain_out_of_a_molehill)**:

> Making a mountain out of a molehill is an idiom referring to over-reactive, histrionic behaviour where a person makes too much of a minor issue.

There are other phrases/idioms which can be used:

> 1. **Make a big deal out of something**.
> 2. **Lay it on with a trowel**.
> 3. **Blow something out of all proportion**.